# Finding a node with no children in a tree like structure with Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a tree like structure roughly like this:

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :parent,   :class_name => self.to_s, :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
   has_many   :children, :class_name => self.to_s, :foreign_key => 'parent_id', :dependent => :destroy
   ...
end
```

I can load all nodes that don't have a parent with this scope:

```
named_scope :not_child, :conditions => 'parent_id IS NULL'
```

But I also need to find nodes that don't have children but can have a parent and I am having a hard time with it. I guess I have to include children_events but then I am lost, I cannot use:

```
named_scope, :faulty_not_parent, :include => :children, :conditions => "node.parent_id IS NULL"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it:

```
named_scope :not_parent, :conditions => "id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM nodes WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL)"
```

Comment: This works, but I edited your answer to search the "nodes" table so it matches the example in your question.  This will avoid confusion with people who read this answer in the future.

Comment: My scope worked on itself but when using other scopes I was having an ambiguous column name problem, had to be a bit more specific on column names:    named_scope :not_parent, :conditions => "nodes.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT nodes.parent_id FROM nodes WHERE nodes.parent_id IS NOT NULL)"

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you use a plugin for this. There are a few, [acts_as_tree](http://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree), [awesome_nested_set](http://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) and my personal recommendation, [ancestry](http://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) which uses only one column to map the structure rather than three as in nested set structures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a SQL guru, so I couldnt' figure out a good way to do this in pure SQL.  Of course, this means I couldn't find a way to do it with named_scopes, either.  But you can find parents, and subtract that from all nodes, like so:

```
def childless
 @childless ||= self.all - self.all(:joins => :children)
end
```

This isn't as elegant as I'd like, since it requires loading a lot in memory.  But it only takes 2 select statements, which is good. I'll be interested to see the other answers.